# Calling a view controller when Static TableViewCell is pressed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my ios app, I have a tableview with 3 static cells. When the first cell is pressed, based on some checks, I want to call different view controllers. Can someone guide me to a simple way to do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need navigate to that controller or just update the content at that view controller?

Comment: just navigate, no update required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You need to either use an if or switch statements to test what indexPath.row is. Navigate to the viewcontroller you want based on the row. There are many ways to do this; you can either set up a segue in storyboard and call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:]
```

or, if the tableview is embedded in a navigation controller; initialize the desired viewcontroller, and use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: animated:]
```

Hard to help any more without more information on how you're trying to do the navigation.